# Given $|a|$ and $|b|$, what is the smallest value of $|a + b|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a and b are vectors such that $|a| = 7$ and $|b| = 11$, then find the smallest possible value of $|a+b|$.

I thought it was $\sqrt{170}$, but its not true. Help! :(

Comment: Did you mean the smallest value of $|a+b|$?  Think about what happens if $a$ and $b$ are in opposite directions.  (You are thinking what happens if they are orthogonal.)

Answer (score 5):

The norm of the sum of two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
||\vec a+\vec b||&=\sqrt{\langle \vec a+\vec b,\vec a+\vec b\rangle}\\\\
&=\sqrt{||\vec a||^2+||\vec b||^2 +2\text{Re}\left(\langle \vec a,\vec b\rangle\right)} \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

From the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) for normed vector spaces

$$|\langle \vec a,\vec b\rangle|\le ||\vec a||\,||\vec b||\,\tag 2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ provides upper and lower bounds for the  norm of the sum as

$$|\,||\vec a||\,-\,||\vec b||\,|\le\,||\vec a+\vec b||\,\le\,||\vec a||\,+\,||\vec b|| \tag 3$$

For the problem herein, $||\vec a||=7$ and $||\vec b||=11$.  Using $(3)$ yields

$$||7-11||\le||\vec a+\vec b||\le7+11\implies 4\le ||\vec a+\vec b||\le 18$$

Heuristically, we can see that the maximum and minimum of the norm of the sum $\vec a+\vec b$ simply occur for those cases for which $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are parallel and anti-parallel, respectively.

Comment: @rtol Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the very best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are collinear and opposed to each other , then 
$|\vec a + \vec b| = 3$.

By the law of cosines,
$$
   |\vec a + \vec b|^2 =
   |\vec a|^2 + |\vec b|^2 - 2|\vec a||\vec b| \cos(\pi - \theta) =
   |\vec a|^2 + |\vec b|^2 + 2|\vec a||\vec b| \cos(\theta)
$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. this quantity is smallest when  $\theta = \pi$, where we get

$$
   |\vec a + \vec b|^2 =
   |\vec a|^2 + |\vec b|^2 - 2|\vec a||\vec b| =
   \left ( |\vec a| - |\vec b| \right)^2
$$

So the minimum value is $\left | |\vec a| - |\vec b| \right|$